# How to get files back from duplicity files?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm new to linux, so bear with me;

When I installed Ubuntu a few days ago, I decided to also get some sort of system to back up my files. I downloaded a program called deja-dup and set it up to backup my files from a partition to my flashdrive. Today, I reinstalled Ubuntu and, thinking that my files were safe on my flashdrive, didn't think I had to do anything. When I opened my flashdrive on my freshly installed OS, I saw these files:

```
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.manifest
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol10.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol11.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol12.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol13.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol14.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol15.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol16.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol17.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol18.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol19.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol1.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol20.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol21.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol2.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol3.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol4.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol5.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol6.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol7.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol8.difftar.gz
duplicity-full.20170928T180609Z.vol9.difftar.gz
duplicity-full-signatures.20170928T180609Z.sigtar.gz
duplicity-inc.20170928T180609Z.to.20170929T061331Z.manifest
duplicity-inc.20170928T180609Z.to.20170929T061331Z.vol1.difftar.gz
duplicity-inc.20170929T061331Z.to.20170930T051749Z.manifest
duplicity-inc.20170929T061331Z.to.20170930T051749Z.vol1.difftar.gz
duplicity-new-signatures.20170928T180609Z.to.20170929T061331Z.sigtar.gz
duplicity-new-signatures.20170929T061331Z.to.20170930T051749Z.sigtar.gz
```

How do I get my files back, or are they lost forever?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: install deja-dub again. it should be able to extract the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Déjà Dup uses an opaque format for files stored in our backup location. So we have to use Déjà Dup or another duplicity-based tool to restore our files. This is opposed to a native format where we can browse and examine our files using any normal file tool.

To restore the files:

1. Open Backups from the System Settings.
2. You should see the restore option here.
3. Point to your back up folder and select the date from which the restore has to begin. Thats it. It should work then.